# how to change the image on click of imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am make a image button .I need to change the image when I click on image button .Actually it change the background image but only for few seconds .why ?

here is my code

```
 <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        />

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/on" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

I need to show on image when I click on image button ..? can I write on java side ? can I write on click listener of image button ?

Comment: You have defined a selector and that is changing the image on `android:state_pressed="true"`. This is the reason the image is changing for couple of seconds.
Yes you can change the image on button click listener.
Let me know the requirement or reframe your question?

Comment: I need to change image on click of image..same thing I need when user press the image button..Actually image is change for few seconds .But i need permantly

Comment: I suppose @Marta has already helped you with it. Cool.

Comment: But till now she didn't provide a answer

Comment: Check her answer. It will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why you are using a selector for your button background and the image changes depending on the state of the button. If it is pressed the image will be "on" and in its normal state (no pressed and no focused) the image will be "off".

EDIT:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton btn;
boolean isPressed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPressed){
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
            }else{
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed; // reverse
        }
    });


}


  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: tenis but it is showing only for second not permanently when I click on image

Comment: i will explain more when I open application it show off image ..when I click it show on image for 1 second I need to display on image permanently after click of image

Comment: Because android:state_pressed="true" sets the drawable (on) while the button is pressed (when you tap the button with your finger). When you untap, the button is unpressed and <item android:drawable="@drawable/off" is fired.

Comment: Ok i will post you an example

Answer (score 1):

> Actually it change the background image but only for few seconds .why ?

I think it's obvious,those items in drawable are for states that ImageButton is pressed by user or in normal mode.

> can I write on java side ? can I write on click listener of image button ?

Yes, and yes again :D if you want to change it when user presses it, just do it like this :

XML layout:

`<ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/off"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        />`

Java side (eg. in you onCreate method)

```
ImageButton favorite;
boolean isFav = false;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ///...
    favorite = findViewById(R.id.favorite);
    favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isFav = !isFav;
            if (isFav){
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);
            }
            else{
                favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.off);
            }
        }
    });
    ///...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the source of the image by providing an absolute path or an internet url dynamically in the onClickListener of the image.

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Here before changing the image you can check if the appropriate                                    //image is set to the view.
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.on);

        }
});
```

and also can be like this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isPressed){
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
            }else{
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            }
            isPressed = !isPressed; // reverse
        }
    });
```