# how to get click event of image button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Could you please  tell me how to get click event of image button in android? Actually, I have one row in which I have textview and image button. I am able to get click event of row but I am not able to get click event of image button.

Actually, I want to change the image when I click on the image button.

I found the code how to change the image of image button:

[how to change the image on click of imagebutton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32245526/how-to-change-the-image-on-click-of-imagebutton)

but how will I apply this on fragment?

Here is my code, I want to get the click event of image button and change the image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/station_name"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#eee345"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
     />


</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment.java**

```
public class Fragmentone  extends Fragment{

    ArrayList<String> name;
    boolean isPressed=false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        name=new ArrayList<String>();
        name.add("First Station");
        name.add("Second Station");


        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item : " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.row_layout,R.id.station_name,name);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);



        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: where is R.layout.fragment_one file?

Answer (score 0):

your ImageButton has id

```
"@+id/favorite"
```

use it to initiate the button in your fragment when onCreateView is called

```
Imagebutton ib = (Imagebutton)findViewbyId(R.id. favorite);
```

next add an onclick listener to your button so you know when it's clicked and take appropriate action

```
ib.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // here you change the image
            }
        });
```

Comment: I am using fragment not activity

Comment: use view.findViewById() where view is the inflated layout which contains the button

Answer (score 0):

In the case of fragment you have to pass the view.

**Example:**

```
@Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton)view.findViewbyId(R.id.favorite);

    imgBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do your stuff 
                } 
            }); 

          return view;
    }
```